# How can I wrap a system library/dependency in a catkin package, and then use that package to provide the system lib in other packages?

Tags: catkin, external-libraries, ros-hydro, find-package, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a system library, such as OpenCV 3.0.0 (for example), installed on my computer in the directory `/opt/OpenCV3`.

I want to wrap the dependencies on OpenCV in my own package, `opencv3`. This way I can use catkin like this:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  opencv3
)
```

So I went ahead and created the opencv3 package. I'm able to find the system library's external .cmake file and build. Here are the important parts of `opencv3`'s `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "/opt/OpenCV3")
...
find_package(catkin REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV 3.0.0 EXACT)
...
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES opencv3
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS
   DEPENDS OpenCV
)
```

Now when I include `opencv3`, my custom package, in other packages as a dependency, the other packages cannot find the OpenCV libraries, and thus they cannot link/build! The OpenCV include directories do transfer over to other packages, however. So when I have this in my `CMakeLists.txt` of other packages which use `opencv3`:

```
message(STATUS ${opencv3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

I get the output:

```
/opt/OpenCV3/include
```

Which is correct. I just can't find out how the `DEPENDS` field of `catkin_package`(...) makes the system dependency libraries transfer to new packages. `catkin_LIBRARIES` and `opencv3_LIBRARIES` did not have the OpenCV libraries in them either...

**Edit for Dirk Thomas :**

The OpenCV_LIBS variable doesn't contain the full absolute filepath to the OpenCV libraries. Doing:

```
message(STATUS ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

yields

```
opencv_videostabopencv_videoopencv_superresopencv_stitchingopencv_softcascadeopencv_shapeopencv_photoopencv_optimopencv_oclopencv_objdetectopencv_nonfreeopencv_mlopencv_legacyopencv_imgprocopencv_highguiopencv_flannopencv_features2dopencv_cudawarpingopencv_cudastereoopencv_cudaoptflowopencv_cudaimgprocopencv_cudafiltersopencv_cudafeatures2dopencv_cudacodecopencv_cudabgsegmopencv_cudaarithmopencv_cudaopencv_coreopencv_contribopencv_calib3d
```

So when I do as you say here:

```
catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    LIBRARIES ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

I get linker errors. My own custom variable works however, which is:

```
set(exec_prefix ${OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH})
    
catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
   LIBRARIES ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_contrib.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_core.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_cuda.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_cudabgsegm.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_cudacodec.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_cudafilters.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_cudaimgproc.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_cudaoptflow.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_cudastereo.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_cudawarping.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_features2d.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_flann.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_highgui.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_legacy.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ml.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ocl.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_optim.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_photo.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_shape.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_softcascade.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_stitching.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_superres.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ts.a ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_video.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_videostab.so tbb /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so rt pthread m dl
)
```

Which is incredibly ugly, but at least the ugliness is captured in a single package `opencv3` and not distributed to other packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154206/how-can-i-wrap-a-system-library/dependency-in-a-catkin-package,-and-then-use-that-package-to-provide-the-system-lib-in-other-packages?/) by [trianta2](https://answers.ros.org/users/8336/trianta2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2014-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`catkin_package(DEPENDS foo)` only works if `foo` follows the recommendation to name its variables `foo_INCLUDE_DIRS`, `foo_LIBRARIES` etc.

`OpenCV` does not follow that recommendation. While the variable for include directories exists the variable containing the libraries is named `OpenCV_LIBS`.

You must therefore pass all individual variable manually since catkin can not infer them:

```
catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    LIBRARIES ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

**Update:**

You should not use `OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH` to prefix your libraries but `OpenCV_LIB_DIR` since the former one is not available on Windows (please read the OpenCV-config.cmake for reference).

Furthermore if you only need a specific subset of OpenCV components you should only find them (rather than implicitly all). That is also one reason why creating a ROS package to only wrap the third-party dependency which already has a decent CMake config file might not make sense...

Anyway you should also avoid listing all libraries explicitly.
Instead you can loop over all found libraries in `OpenCV_LIBS` and use `find_library` with the hint to search in `OpenCV_LIB_DIR` to actually resolve the exact library file.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [trianta2](https://answers.ros.org/users/8336/trianta2/) on 2014-04-18**:
Hi Dirk. Please see my edit.